# "Backup your file encryption key" message even if no files are encrypted

Tags: windows, backup, encryption

Since a few days, I get this message at boot:

[image]

I probably opened files, from a ZIP, appearing in "green" (encrypted?) in the explorer, but I deleted them. Doing `cipher /u /n /h` shows that no files are encrypted on my system:

[image]

Why does this boot message appear?

Comment: You have checked for encrypted files on disk E, but you need to also check on C and D (all existing disks). Run `cypher` from an elevated CMD. If you're sure you have no encrypted files, you can disable encryption in an elevated CMD with the command `fsutil behavior set disableencryption 1`.

Comment: The EFS key will not go away just because you no longer have any encrypted files. You should back it up, just in case.

Comment: @DanielB Where can I list all EFS keys installed, and how to remove them?

Comment: @Basj - EFS certificates are stored in the certificate store.